# Merge/Fuse a list of tuples in a certain way

Tags: python, algorithm

Given a list of tuples that represent edges:

```py
edges = [(2, 4), (3, 4), (6, 8), (6, 9), (7, 10), (11, 13)]
```

I want to merge or blend those edges to get a list of merged tuples, for example `(2, 4), (3, 4)` will be merged into `(2, 4)`.

The final output of the the list above should look like:

```py
[(2, 4), (6, 10), (11, 13)]
```

My idea is to use a double `for` loop to iterate over the list and find intersections and substitute the 2 edges with `(min(e1[0], e2[0]), max(e1[1], e2[1]))` but this method won't
work for all cases.

Any good thoughts?

Comment: According to what you say you currently think could work, would the result not be `[(2, 4), (6, 9), (7, 13)]`?

Comment: it rather would be `[(2, 4), (6, 9), (6, 10), (11, 13)]`

Comment: Look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65486633/5237560

Comment: Also I'm wondering if it could be done in less than O(n**2)

Comment: @AlainT. this answers my problem

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I want to input a list of intervals and check the intervals of the union of overlapping intervals and the intervals of non-overlapping intervals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65485834/i-want-to-input-a-list-of-intervals-and-check-the-intervals-of-the-union-of-over)

Comment: @abdelhalimresu Does my answer solve the question? It should be less than O(N^2) depending on the sorting complexity.

Comment: @AlainT. turns out I need tuples as elements of the list not lists, but that's okay the result after transformation into tuples is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my solution:

```
edges = [(2, 4), (3, 4), (6, 8), (6, 9), (7, 10), (11, 13)]
edges = sorted(edges, key=lambda x:(x[0], -x[1]))

fused = []
i = 0
while i < len(edges):
    start,end = edges[i]
    for j in range(i+1, len(edges)):
        s,e = edges[j]
        if s <= end:
            # edges[j] is included in the fused range
            # Update end to the greater value
            end = max(e, end)
        else:
            break
    fused.append((start, end))
    del edges[i:j]
print(fused)
```

## Explanation:

The logic works as follows: we sort the list in ascending order of the start values. If two ranges have the same start value, we arrange them in **descending** order of their end elements. This way two ranges with the same start value will be 'eaten up' by the range with the farther end value.

Now that the list is sorted in this *unique* way, there's a nice little property here: If you start from the first range, you can decide whether or not you want to fuse with the next range or not. If you do fuse with it, then update the end of the first range to merge with the 'fusable' range. If you decide NOT to fuse with it, then everything from the first range till now will get fused and added to the new list.

---

```
edges = sorted(edges, key=lambda x:(x[0], -x[1]))
```

Sorts edges in ascending order of the start values and descending order of end values.

---

```
del edges[i:j]
```

Deletes all the fused ranges from the original list. This is important because `i` always points to the new range that we'll start fusing from.